# Can malware be installed on a mobile phone when the user opens an sms?

Tags: malware, mobile, phone, instant-messaging

Is it possible for an adversary send malware over messages? I mean, when the victim clicks on the message sent by the attacker, a malware should be installed into his phone (in background). The hacker should then be able to steal all the data in the victim's phone. Is it really possible? How to perform this attack? What are the possible ways to mitigate risk?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. There's in general two main ways to achieve this:

1. Social engineering. Fool the user into installing a piece of software. Installing software not in the app stores are doable on Android, and quite a lot more difficult on iOS.
2. Find a vulnerability, that either lets you install arbitrary apps without user interaction, or let's the browser leak the desired data to you. Sandboxing attempts to avoid browser data leaks.

It's not an easy task, but it's not entirely unlikely either.

The easiest way to mitigate the risk is not to access unknown or unexpected links, or in case of messages pertaining to be from a service, e.g. your bank, access them by manually entering the address in the browser. This will mitigate for instance [Punycode attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack).

TL;DR: Software may have security holes.

Comment: By social engineering do you mean sending a link to an apk file and asking him to install it?

Comment: Essentially yes. Or, rather luring the victim to do something the victim doesn't know he's doing.

Comment: If possible, can you please explain about a vulnerability and how to exploit it to send malware over sms? The social engineering attack is noticeable by the user. I would like to know how to install malware without the user knowing it.

Comment: There's no publicly known vulnerabilities that lets you do this in Android. One notable historic example was [Stagefright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagefright_(bug)) - which required MMS and SMS, but nevertheless was a serious issue.